# plane cubics and conic bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, discriminant

It is well known that any plane cubic curve can be obtained as the discriminant locus of a conic bundle (actually even just of a net of conics). Does this hold true also for all nodal cubics (with double lines over the nodes)? How does one see this?

Comment: For the smooth plane cubic, the net of conics is given by a surface of bidegree (1,2). The problem is equivalent - I think - to checking wether all nodal plane cubics are symmetric determinantal. This seems quite true....

Comment: I don't know how to edit the comment, actually it is hypersurface, not surface of course.


Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, at least if we're not in characteristic 2.
Since all nodal cubics are projectively equivalent, it is enough to find one example.  Trying a few symmetric $3 \times 3$ determinants soon turns up the matrix
$$
M = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
  x & x & y \cr 
  x & z & 0 \cr
  y & 0 & x
\end{array} \right]
$$
with determinant $x^2(z-x)-zy^2$.  So the discriminant locus of
the associated net of conics is $zy^2 = x^2(z-x)$, which has a
node at $(x:y:z) = (0:0:1)$ [set $z=1$ to get the more familiar
affine model $y^2 = x^2 - x^3$ with a node at the origin].
At that point $M$ becomes
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \cr
  0 & 1 & 0 \cr
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right],
$$
where the conic degenerates to a double line as desired.

Comment: Thank you! so everything I stated stays true for nodal curves: cool.